# How to type-annotate tensorflow.Session() in python3

Tags: tensorflow, typing, annotate

I tried to annotate type for argument of `tf.Session()`.

On command line, `type(tf.Session())` is just like this:

```py
>>> type(tf.Session())
>>> <class 'tensorflow.python.client.session.Session'>
```

Then, I tried to annotate like this.

```py
def func_with_sess_arg(image: np.ndarray,
                       sess: tf.python.client.session.Session):
                       ...
```

But it raises

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "func_with_sess_arg.py", line 13, in <module>
    sess: tf.python.client.session.Session):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'python'
```

How can I annotate type of argument for tf.Session() correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just type

```
def func_with_sess_arg(image: np.ndarray,
                       sess: tf.Session):
                       ...
```